# space consumption of null columns in sqlite db

Tags: sqlite

Say I have a db column that's only used rarely by records in my sqlite db (for the rest of the records, the value is null), would those null columns consume as much space comparable to if those columns were non-existent?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my test program, NULL values have consumed one byte per row. If the average row size in your table will be above 100 bytes, then yes, it's comparable to nonexistent.

Comment: For some reason I'm getting about 1.2 bytes per NULL column per row in my testing, but yeah, +1. Not sure I would compare it to non-existent though, unless you're talking about one or two columns. If you had 500 such columns for example, a million rows would use 500 MB of additional space versus not having those columns. For a single column over a million rows it would be only 1 MB difference though.

Comment: just curious how SQLite packs it so tight... how does it distinguish between NULL and (for instance) an INTEGER that fits into a single byte, not to mention all the other integer sizes and other types a field could be.

Comment: I believe it packs small because each value is prefixed with its type. In this case that prefix is a byte kind of like a tagged union: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union