# `object` foreign key? sql table design

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 8 tables that causes a user message. Is it possible to have a table with the columns

```
messageID, user, type, fID
```

where type and fId are used together to figure out what table fID points to? Is that possible? I think not. Should I create 8+ different message tables all like this?

```
MessageType1
    messageID, user, fID
MessageType2
    messageID, user, fID
... up to 8 or more
```

I'm using sqlite but I can use mysql or psql. I use SqlServer at work so a solution for that is ok

Comment: What about 8 different nullable foreign key columns, with a check constraint that only one is not null? How different are the other tables from eachother? Could you combine them into one table, with a type column?

Comment: @JeffS: Wouldnt that use significantly more space?

Comment: Since this is one of the few pieces of data I think is ok to be corrupted or missing/deleted i'll just not use a FK.

Comment: Depending on which DBMS you use, you can also later add a trigger to enforce the constraint.

Comment: @acidzombie24 a NULL take up one byte of space in sqlite, so for 8 of them it would be 8 bytes per row. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051923/space-consumption-of-null-columns-in-sqlite-db